# How to add auto-dimensioning to Photoshop or Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, export, design-process, overlay

I have layers with different elements in each layer.
Each elemnt have their own margin from edge.

Is it possible to export file to png\jpg\etc with overlayed layer with dimensions of each separate element (maybe text sizes too)?

I mean smth like that: 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried slices?

Comment: Do you mean crop all elements to separate files? I need one png file with dp\px units on it like on the image aboe. I need this one file to make calculation moer simple.